# Max number of consecutive non-missing records cross rows in SAS

Tags: sas

I have in the following data for persons 1 and 2, consecutive dates, and variable X. I want to find the maximum number of consecutive non-missing values per person. For person 1, it is 3 coming from  09MAY2021, 10MAY2021, and 11MAY2021. For person 2, it is 6 coming from  09JUN2021-14JUN2021.

```
PERSON DATE     X
1   05MAY2021   .
1   06MAY2021   5
1   07MAY2021   .
1   08MAY2021   .
1   09MAY2021   4
1   10MAY2021   5
1   11MAY2021   3
1   12MAY2021   .
1   13MAY2021   .
1   14MAY2021   5
2   05JUN2021   0
2   06JUN2021   2
2   07JUN2021   .
2   08JUN2021   .
2   09JUN2021   5
2   10JUN2021   7
2   11JUN2021   5
2   12JUN2021   6
2   13JUN2021   5
2   14JUN2021   5
```

Comment: welcome :-) What does your desried result look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of all consecutive non-missing dates with by-group processing, `retain`, and the sum statement. For each person we'll increment a counter by 1 when the data is not missing. We'll store the biggest value we find into `max_consecutive`. If our number is greater than `max_consecutive`, we'll overwrite it with the larger number.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by person;

    /* Do not reset these variables at each row */
    retain max_consecutive
           date_start
           date_end
    ;

    /* Reset the counter for each person or missing value, otherwise count */
    if(first.person OR missing(x) ) then consecutive = 0;
        else consecutive+1;

    /* Reset the max consecutive for each person */
    if(first.person) then max_consecutive = 0;

    /* Keep track of the max consecutive non-missing dates */
    if(consecutive > max_consecutive) then do;
        max_consecutive = consecutive;

        /* Keep track of the start/end dates */
        date_start = intnx('day', date, -1*max_consecutive+1);
        date_end   = date;
    end;

    /* Only output one row per person */
    if(last.person) then output;

    format date_start date_end date9.;

    keep person max_consecutive date_start date_end;
 run;
```

Output:

```
PERSON  max_consecutive date_start  date_end
1       3               09MAY2021   11MAY2021
2       6               09JUN2021   14JUN2021
```

Comment: Please note that `retain` does not reset variables only if they do not exist in the read dataset (here, have). That's an important point to consider....

Answer (score 0):

Another way.  Notice the creation of grouping variable R.

```
data test;
   input PERSON DATE:date. X;
   r = ifn(missing(x),0,1);
   format date date9.;
   cards;
1   05MAY2021   .
1   06MAY2021   5
1   07MAY2021   .
1   08MAY2021   .
1   09MAY2021   4
1   10MAY2021   5
1   11MAY2021   3
1   12MAY2021   .
1   13MAY2021   .
1   14MAY2021   5
2   05JUN2021   0
2   06JUN2021   2
2   07JUN2021   .
2   08JUN2021   .
2   09JUN2021   5
2   10JUN2021   7
2   11JUN2021   5
2   12JUN2021   6
2   13JUN2021   5
2   14JUN2021   5
;;;;
   run;
proc summary data=test nway missing;
   by person r notsorted;
   output out=test2(drop=_:) n(x)=nx min(date)=Start max(date)=End;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc summary nway data=test2;
   class person;
   output out=max(drop=_:) max(nx)=maxnx;
   run;
data test3;
   merge test2 max;
   by person;
   if nx eq maxnx;
   drop maxnx;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRV0R.png)

Comment: Thanks very much. I tried the second option. Works great!